# Calling a method to print an array in single line

Tags: java, arrays, methods, printing, output

I've been trying to work out what is wrong but I can't seem to figure it out. Essentially my code will get the user to input N size of array. The array will then be filled with random numbers generated from 1-100. I have a printArray method which prints the elements of an array in a single line that I've tested on a fixed array and it works, but when I call it from the generated array it gives me a lot of extra 0's. 
Here is the code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Size of array:"); //prompts the user enter size of array
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
            printArray(array);
```

and here is the display method:

```
public static void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

        else if (i == array.length) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

        else
            System.out.print("," + array[i]);

    }
}
```

When I run the code it will generate an output like this:(3 as example)

Size of array to sort?
3
36,0,036,68,036,68,75, where it's supposed to just be 36,68,75.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the array multiple times in a single line.

In the first iteration you print `36,0,0`, In the second iteration you print `36,68,0` and only in the final iteration you print the fully initialized array - `36,68,75`.

Move `printArray(array);` to the end of the loop. You might want to add a `println` at the end of `printArray`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
}
printArray(array);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness..I was so fixated on other things I did not even realize that. Thank you so much! *Rookie mistake*

Comment: @Anon54 BTW, I don't know if writing yourself a method to print an array was part of some exercise/assignment. If it's not, you can simply use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)));`

Comment: We were asked to call the printArray method for an unsorted and sorted list, and werent allowed to use the Arrays class. I will keep that in mind!